# java script validation for password using array

Tags: javascript

want to apply validation through javascript code.
here "fpass" is the id of  textbox1

```
 var spcl=['@','$','%','&'];
 var i;
 var len=spcl.length;



    for(i=0;i<len;i++){
    document.write(spcl[i] + " ");
    }  
        if( "%" in spcl[i]){
        document.write("good");
        }else{
        document.write("no special characters");
        }
```

Comment: And your question is ?

Comment: You can try it with regex.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/40944/verifying-password-strength-using-javascript

Comment: dont want to use regular expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your if statement is outside of the loop, so fix it:

```
for(i=0;i<len;i++){
    document.write(spcl[i] + " ");
    if("%" in spcl[i]){
        document.write("good");
    }else{
        document.write("no special characters");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read how [`in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) works...

Comment: but how to validate password  for special character  using array?

Comment: what do you mean, do you mean break out of the loop when condition is met

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I guess you wan't that the input text of the password field has any of those chars in your  "spcl"-array. So I would do it like this:

Update in order to match you comment:

```
var spcl=['@','$','%','&'];
var count = 0;

function validate(s) {
    document.getElementById('validationtext').innerHTML = check(s);
    count = 0;
}

function check(s) {
    for(var i = 0; i<s.length; i++) {
        if (spcl.indexOf(s[i]) > -1) {
            count++;
            if (count > 1) return "good";
        }
    }
    return "no special characters";
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gczvfzwu/2/)**

Comment: i want to validate password field without  using regular expressiion.

input field must contain 2 special characters

Comment: Look at the updated code. Now it should work for you.